# pagination using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am doing pagination using jquery datatable. 
My data is not exctaly table, 1 row from db say id, name, location...... i display in jsp in 3 rows like first row id,second row name then third row location...i have 1500 hunderd rows in db.
For this i need to do pagination.
And also when the user clicks on next link it should go to server for next records.

I know how to get the restricted number of results from server side ....

I need help for jsp configuration.....i am new to jquery...how to configure datatable.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Questions on SO should show the code you've tried, not be just a general request for solutions. See http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) you can set `"bProcessing": true`, `"bServerSide": true` and the source `"sAjaxSource": "yourFile.php"` when you init your table.
Then on your php you have to return the same object as bellow:

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57", // total number of rows
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57", // number of rows after the filter
  "aaData": [//your data]
}
```

You can see what parameters you have to use on the [server-side processing reference](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side).

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your reply..
i understand "bProcessing": true, "bServerSide": true . 

but "sAjaxSource": "yourFile.php" i can not understand.....
i am not using php.

i am developing this application using liferay portal 6 and DAO in hibernate.
In dao layer using hibernate i can get the restricted number of records to the controller.

My question is what i should specify in the "sAjaxSource": 
and also where will i pass the page number to the controller to get the next set of records.

Comment: @user1457957 Look the reference at Initialisation parameters. It will explain what's ajaxSource (where're your rows' data).

Comment: i looked at reference...but all the examples are mentioning abt php files. Actually in my portlet to send a request i use <portlet:actionurl>. so how do set this in sAjaxsource?

Comment: can anybody tell me how to get the page number which user clicked? in what variable it is stroed?