# Using Jquery Datatable with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to use the [jquery datatable plugin](http://www.datatables.net) in my angularjs project. but my question is does it support **lazy loading** of value for angularjs? i want beacuse i have many row. how to use  [datatable pipeline](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) with angularjs.

There is a solution for pagination in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109754/pagination-using-jquery-datatable). How to use the solution with angularjs?

Comment: It would help if you posted what you have tried so far.

Comment: Questions on SO should show the code you've tried, not be just a general request for solutions. See http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Please mark accepted if any solutions worked.

Answer (score 44):

Take a look at this: AngularJS+JQuery(datatable)

FULL code: http://jsfiddle.net/zdam/7kLFU/

JQuery Datatables's Documentation: http://www.datatables.net/

```
var dialogApp = angular.module('tableExample', []);

    dialogApp.directive('myTable', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // apply DataTable options, use defaults if none specified by user
            var options = {};
            if (attrs.myTable.length > 0) {
                options = scope.$eval(attrs.myTable);
            } else {
                options = {
                    "bStateSave": true,
                    "iCookieDuration": 2419200, /* 1 month */
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bLengthChange": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bDestroy": true
                };
            }

            // Tell the dataTables plugin what columns to use
            // We can either derive them from the dom, or use setup from the controller           
            var explicitColumns = [];
            element.find('th').each(function(index, elem) {
                explicitColumns.push($(elem).text());
            });
            if (explicitColumns.length > 0) {
                options["aoColumns"] = explicitColumns;
            } else if (attrs.aoColumns) {
                options["aoColumns"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumns);
            }

            // aoColumnDefs is dataTables way of providing fine control over column config
            if (attrs.aoColumnDefs) {
                options["aoColumnDefs"] = scope.$eval(attrs.aoColumnDefs);
            }

            if (attrs.fnRowCallback) {
                options["fnRowCallback"] = scope.$eval(attrs.fnRowCallback);
            }

            // apply the plugin
            var dataTable = element.dataTable(options);



            // watch for any changes to our data, rebuild the DataTable
            scope.$watch(attrs.aaData, function(value) {
                var val = value || null;
                if (val) {
                    dataTable.fnClearTable();
                    dataTable.fnAddData(scope.$eval(attrs.aaData));
                }
            });
        };
    });

function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.message = '';            

        $scope.myCallback = function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {            
            $('td:eq(2)', nRow).bind('click', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.someClickHandler(aData);
                });
            });
            return nRow;
        };

        $scope.someClickHandler = function(info) {
            $scope.message = 'clicked: '+ info.price;
        };

        $scope.columnDefs = [ 
            { "mDataProp": "category", "aTargets":[0]},
            { "mDataProp": "name", "aTargets":[1] },
            { "mDataProp": "price", "aTargets":[2] }
        ]; 

        $scope.overrideOptions = {
            "bStateSave": true,
            "iCookieDuration": 2419200, /* 1 month */
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bDestroy": true
        };


        $scope.sampleProductCategories = [

              {
                "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
                "price": 53.9,
                  "category": "Classic Cars",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
                "price": 62.16,
            "category": "Classic Cars",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
                "price": 47.25,
            "category": "Classic Cars",
                  "action":"x"
              }
              ,
              {
                "name": "1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead",
                "price": 24.23,
            "category": "Motorcycles",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1957 Vespa GS150",
                "price": 32.95,
            "category": "Motorcycles",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1960 BSA Gold Star DBD34",
                "price": 37.32,
            "category": "Motorcycles",
                  "action":"x"
              }
           ,
              {
                "name": "1900s Vintage Bi-Plane",
                "price": 34.25,
            "category": "Planes",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1900s Vintage Tri-Plane",
                "price": 36.23,
            "category": "Planes",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1928 British Royal Navy Airplane",
                "price": 66.74,
            "category": "Planes",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "1980s Black Hawk Helicopter",
                "price": 77.27,
            "category": "Planes",
                  "action":"x"
              },
              {
                "name": "ATA: B757-300",
                "price": 59.33,
            "category": "Planes",
                  "action":"x"
              }

        ];            

}
```

Comment: Any idea how to reorder columns in $scope.columnDefs? I have a parameter and depending on that i must display diferent column order

Comment: This is an awesome answer and bit of code, but angular should be more declarative.  Meaning, I don't want to define an aoColumns in my scope.  That belongs in the **View**.  (Array of data/title objects).  This will start to work if you correct this line of code: `explicitColumns.push({ data: $(elem).text() });`.

Answer (score 19):

After many hours of experimenting with using jQueryDataTables with Angular, I found what I needed was available with a native Angular directive called ng-table. It provides sorting, pagination, and ajax reloads (sort of lazy loading capable with a few tweaks).

Comment: Just pointing out that this is an _alternative_ to datatables, but not actually *[DataTables | Table plug-in for jQuery](https://datatables.net/)*

Comment: `ng-table` is *not* a native angular directive.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a new answer just as a reference for future researchers and as nobody mentioned that yet I think it's valid.

Another good option is **ng-grid** http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/.

And there's a beta version (http://ui-grid.info/) available already with some improvements:

- Native AngularJS implementation, no jQuery
- Performs well with large data sets; even 10,000+ rows
- Plugin architecture allows you to use only the features you need

**UPDATE:**

It seems UI GRID is not beta anymore.

> With the 3.0 release, the repository has been renamed from "ng-grid"
>   to "ui-grid".

Comment: UI Grid looks extremely promising!

Comment: update on this - 1 year later - UI Grid is hands down the best solution I've encountered

Answer (score 5):

For AngularJs you have to use "angular-datatables.min.js" file for datatable settings. You will get this from http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome.

After that you can write code like below,

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('AngularWayApp', ['datatables']);
</script>

<div ng-app="AngularWayApp" ng-controller="AngularWayCtrl">
  <table id="example" datatable="ng" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><b>UserID</b></th>
        <th><b>Firstname</b></th>
        <th><b>Lastname</b></th>
        <th><b>Email</b></th>
        <th><b>Actions</b></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="testingClick(user)">
        <td>{{user.UserId}}</td>
        <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
        <td>
           <span ng-click="editUser(user)" style="color:blue;cursor: pointer; font-weight:500; font-size:15px" class="btnAdd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span ng-click="deleteUser(user)" style="color:red; cursor: pointer; font-weight:500; font-size:15px" class="btnRed">Delete</span>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: As said I just included angular-datatables.min.js and ui bootstrap tpsl.js it worked like cucumber  Thank you so much 

Answer (score 3):

I know it's tempting to use drag and drop angular modules created by other devs - but actually, unless you are doing something non-standard like dynamically adding / removing rows from the ng-repeated data set by calling `$http` services chance are you really don't need a directive based solution, so if you do go this direction you probably just created extra watchers you don't actually need.

What this implementation provides:

- Pagination is always correct
- Filtering is always correct (even if you add custom filters but of course they just need to be in the same closure)

The implementation is easy. Just use angular's version of jQuery dom ready from your view's controller:

**Inside your controller:**

```
'use strict';

var yourApp = angular.module('yourApp.yourController.controller', []);

yourApp.controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $q, $timeout) {

    $scope.users = [
        {
            email: 'email@address.com',
            name: {
                first: 'User',
                last: 'Last Name'
            },
            phone: '(416) 555-5555',
            permissions: 'Admin'
        },
        {
            email: 'example@email.com',
            name: {
                first: 'First',
                last: 'Last'
            },
            phone: '(514) 222-1111',
            permissions: 'User'
        }
    ];

    angular.element(document).ready( function () {
         dTable = $('#user_table')
         dTable.DataTable();
     });

}]);
```

**Now in your html view can do:**

```
<div class="table table-data clear-both" data-ng-show="viewState === possibleStates[0]">
        <table id="user_table" class="users list dtable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Permissions</th>
                    <th class="blank-cell"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.name.first }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.name.last }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.permissions }}</td>
                    <td class="users controls blank-cell">
                        <a class="btn pointer" data-ng-click="showEditUser( $index )">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: This still results in an error for me as angular and jquery are stepping on each other while manupulating the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

visit this link for reference:http://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/RRBzda

```
<script>  
var app=angular.module('formvalid', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.utils']);
app.controller('validationCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.data=[
        [
            "Tiger Nixon",
            "System Architect",
            "Edinburgh",
            "5421",
            "2011\/04\/25",
            "$320,800"
        ],
        [
            "Garrett Winters",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "8422",
            "2011\/07\/25",
            "$170,750"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton Cox",
            "Junior Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "1562",
            "2009\/01\/12",
            "$86,000"
        ],
        [
            "Cedric Kelly",
            "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "6224",
            "2012\/03\/29",
            "$433,060"
        ],
        [
            "Airi Satou",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "5407",
            "2008\/11\/28",
            "$162,700"
        ],
        [
            "Brielle Williamson",
            "Integration Specialist",
            "New York",
            "4804",
            "2012\/12\/02",
            "$372,000"
        ],
        [
            "Herrod Chandler",
            "Sales Assistant",
            "San Francisco",
            "9608",
            "2012\/08\/06",
            "$137,500"
        ],
        [
            "Rhona Davidson",
            "Integration Specialist",
            "Tokyo",
            "6200",
            "2010\/10\/14",
            "$327,900"
        ],
        [
            "Colleen Hurst",
            "Javascript Developer",
            "San Francisco",
            "2360",
            "2009\/09\/15",
            "$205,500"
        ],
        [
            "Sonya Frost",
            "Software Engineer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "1667",
            "2008\/12\/13",
            "$103,600"
        ],
        [
            "Jena Gaines",
            "Office Manager",
            "London",
            "3814",
            "2008\/12\/19",
            "$90,560"
        ],
        [
            "Quinn Flynn",
            "Support Lead",
            "Edinburgh",
            "9497",
            "2013\/03\/03",
            "$342,000"
        ],
        [
            "Charde Marshall",
            "Regional Director",
            "San Francisco",
            "6741",
            "2008\/10\/16",
            "$470,600"
        ],
        [
            "Haley Kennedy",
            "Senior Marketing Designer",
            "London",
            "3597",
            "2012\/12\/18",
            "$313,500"
        ],
        [
            "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
            "Regional Director",
            "London",
            "1965",
            "2010\/03\/17",
            "$385,750"
        ],
        [
            "Michael Silva",
            "Marketing Designer",
            "London",
            "1581",
            "2012\/11\/27",
            "$198,500"
        ],
        [
            "Paul Byrd",
            "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
            "New York",
            "3059",
            "2010\/06\/09",
            "$725,000"
        ],
        [
            "Gloria Little",
            "Systems Administrator",
            "New York",
            "1721",
            "2009\/04\/10",
            "$237,500"
        ],
        [
            "Bradley Greer",
            "Software Engineer",
            "London",
            "2558",
            "2012\/10\/13",
            "$132,000"
        ],
        [
            "Dai Rios",
            "Personnel Lead",
            "Edinburgh",
            "2290",
            "2012\/09\/26",
            "$217,500"
        ],
        [
            "Jenette Caldwell",
            "Development Lead",
            "New York",
            "1937",
            "2011\/09\/03",
            "$345,000"
        ],
        [
            "Yuri Berry",
            "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
            "New York",
            "6154",
            "2009\/06\/25",
            "$675,000"
        ],
        [
            "Caesar Vance",
            "Pre-Sales Support",
            "New York",
            "8330",
            "2011\/12\/12",
            "$106,450"
        ],
        [
            "Doris Wilder",
            "Sales Assistant",
            "Sidney",
            "3023",
            "2010\/09\/20",
            "$85,600"
        ],
        [
            "Angelica Ramos",
            "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
            "London",
            "5797",
            "2009\/10\/09",
            "$1,200,000"
        ],
        [
            "Gavin Joyce",
            "Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "8822",
            "2010\/12\/22",
            "$92,575"
        ],
        [
            "Jennifer Chang",
            "Regional Director",
            "Singapore",
            "9239",
            "2010\/11\/14",
            "$357,650"
        ],
        [
            "Brenden Wagner",
            "Software Engineer",
            "San Francisco",
            "1314",
            "2011\/06\/07",
            "$206,850"
        ],
        [
            "Fiona Green",
            "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
            "San Francisco",
            "2947",
            "2010\/03\/11",
            "$850,000"
        ],
        [
            "Shou Itou",
            "Regional Marketing",
            "Tokyo",
            "8899",
            "2011\/08\/14",
            "$163,000"
        ],
        [
            "Michelle House",
            "Integration Specialist",
            "Sidney",
            "2769",
            "2011\/06\/02",
            "$95,400"
        ],
        [
            "Suki Burks",
            "Developer",
            "London",
            "6832",
            "2009\/10\/22",
            "$114,500"
        ],
        [
            "Prescott Bartlett",
            "Technical Author",
            "London",
            "3606",
            "2011\/05\/07",
            "$145,000"
        ],
        [
            "Gavin Cortez",
            "Team Leader",
            "San Francisco",
            "2860",
            "2008\/10\/26",
            "$235,500"
        ],
        [
            "Martena Mccray",
            "Post-Sales support",
            "Edinburgh",
            "8240",
            "2011\/03\/09",
            "$324,050"
        ],
        [
            "Unity Butler",
            "Marketing Designer",
            "San Francisco",
            "5384",
            "2009\/12\/09",
            "$85,675"
        ],
        [
            "Howard Hatfield",
            "Office Manager",
            "San Francisco",
            "7031",
            "2008\/12\/16",
            "$164,500"
        ],
        [
            "Hope Fuentes",
            "Secretary",
            "San Francisco",
            "6318",
            "2010\/02\/12",
            "$109,850"
        ],
        [
            "Vivian Harrell",
            "Financial Controller",
            "San Francisco",
            "9422",
            "2009\/02\/14",
            "$452,500"
        ],
        [
            "Timothy Mooney",
            "Office Manager",
            "London",
            "7580",
            "2008\/12\/11",
            "$136,200"
        ],
        [
            "Jackson Bradshaw",
            "Director",
            "New York",
            "1042",
            "2008\/09\/26",
            "$645,750"
        ],
        [
            "Olivia Liang",
            "Support Engineer",
            "Singapore",
            "2120",
            "2011\/02\/03",
            "$234,500"
        ],
        [
            "Bruno Nash",
            "Software Engineer",
            "London",
            "6222",
            "2011\/05\/03",
            "$163,500"
        ],
        [
            "Sakura Yamamoto",
            "Support Engineer",
            "Tokyo",
            "9383",
            "2009\/08\/19",
            "$139,575"
        ],
        [
            "Thor Walton",
            "Developer",
            "New York",
            "8327",
            "2013\/08\/11",
            "$98,540"
        ],
        [
            "Finn Camacho",
            "Support Engineer",
            "San Francisco",
            "2927",
            "2009\/07\/07",
            "$87,500"
        ],
        [
            "Serge Baldwin",
            "Data Coordinator",
            "Singapore",
            "8352",
            "2012\/04\/09",
            "$138,575"
        ],
        [
            "Zenaida Frank",
            "Software Engineer",
            "New York",
            "7439",
            "2010\/01\/04",
            "$125,250"
        ],
        [
            "Zorita Serrano",
            "Software Engineer",
            "San Francisco",
            "4389",
            "2012\/06\/01",
            "$115,000"
        ],
        [
            "Jennifer Acosta",
            "Junior Javascript Developer",
            "Edinburgh",
            "3431",
            "2013\/02\/01",
            "$75,650"
        ],
        [
            "Cara Stevens",
            "Sales Assistant",
            "New York",
            "3990",
            "2011\/12\/06",
            "$145,600"
        ],
        [
            "Hermione Butler",
            "Regional Director",
            "London",
            "1016",
            "2011\/03\/21",
            "$356,250"
        ],
        [
            "Lael Greer",
            "Systems Administrator",
            "London",
            "6733",
            "2009\/02\/27",
            "$103,500"
        ],
        [
            "Jonas Alexander",
            "Developer",
            "San Francisco",
            "8196",
            "2010\/07\/14",
            "$86,500"
        ],
        [
            "Shad Decker",
            "Regional Director",
            "Edinburgh",
            "6373",
            "2008\/11\/13",
            "$183,000"
        ],
        [
            "Michael Bruce",
            "Javascript Developer",
            "Singapore",
            "5384",
            "2011\/06\/27",
            "$183,000"
        ],
        [
            "Donna Snider",
            "Customer Support",
            "New York",
            "4226",
            "2011\/01\/25",
            "$112,000"
        ]
    ]


$scope.dataTableOpt = {
  //if any ajax call 
  };
});
</script>
<div class="container" ng-app="formvalid">
      <div class="panel" data-ng-controller="validationCtrl">
      <div class="panel-heading border">    
        <h2>Data table using jquery datatable in Angularjs </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered bordered table-striped table-condensed datatable" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="n in data">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{n[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{n[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{n[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{n[3]}}</td>
                <td>{{n[4] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... How can we achieve the excel button in the Top Left using ui-otpions. Actually I need two options... One with as it is mention in the above.. Second one is excel button in the Top Left instead of View By Option... My script:

var table02 = $('.scrollableTable.scrollable-dataTable-icons table').DataTable({
"scrollX": true,
lengthChange: false,
buttons: [{
extend: 'excel',
text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
titleAttr: 'Export to Excel'
}]
});
table02.columns.adjust();
table02.buttons().container().appendTo('.dataTables_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');