# is it possible to use datatablejs with angularjs or any alternative to datatablejs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, fixed-header-tables

I am struck in my application, where I have `thousands of data for creating reports and dataentry` forms for the user. Previously I use to *manage with json call from backend with `datatablejs` for fixing header and column*.

But now I need to use `angularjs` as an framework for frontend side, and need to *`fix header and column` of the table with `datatable js`*.But i am unable to do the thing.

Please help me out of this stuff.

**Can it be possible to use datatable js with angular,** if not then please suggest me the way to fix header and column of the table with responsive solution? Any alternate solutions are also appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Jquery Datatable with AngularJs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242455/using-jquery-datatable-with-angularjs)

Comment: You can make your own directive to wrap up datatable or use existing one 
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

Answer (score 1):

One way is using bootstrap for table and angular js has built in directives like ng-repeat which can be used to populate the data within a scope variable into the table. The columns can be made dynamic as well with the use of ng-repeat.

This is my html  code

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-init="initialise()">
    <table class="table table-condensed shortMargin" id="dashboardTable">
        <thead id="table-header">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="sortData('respondentName')">
                    Respondent Name
                    <div ng-class="getSortClass('respondentName')"></div>
                </th>

                <th ng-click="sortData('assessmentTitle')">
                    Assessment Title
                    <div ng-class="getSortClass('assessmentTitle')"></div>
                </th>

                <th ng-click="sortData('positionTitle')">
                    Position Title
                    <div ng-class="getSortClass('positionTitle')"></div>
                </th>

                <th ng-click="sortData('status')">
                    Status
                    <div ng-class="getSortClass('status')"></div>
                </th>

                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="task in TaskList | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort ">

                <td><a href="" ng-click="SetDetails(task)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RespondentDetailModal">{{task.respondentName}}</a></td>

                <td>
                    {{task.assessmentTitle}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{task.positionTitle}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{task.status}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm submit" type="button" ng-click="showTaskDetails(task)" data-target="#TaskDetails">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

This is my js code

```
 $scope.initialise = function () {

        ngProgressLite.start();

        getWorkFlowByRoleName($scope.role[0]);
    };

function getWorkFlowByRoleName(name) {
        apiService.get('workFlowStatus/GetActiveTasksByRoleName/' + name,
                        name,
                        getWorkFlowByRoleNameCompleted,
                        reviewTasksLoadFailed
                        );
    }
    function getWorkFlowByRoleNameCompleted(response) {
        $scope.TaskList = response.data;

    }
    function reviewTasksLoadFailed(response) {
        if (response.statusText == "Not Found")
            $scope.taskEmptyMsg = "No tasks are assigned to you yet!! ";
    }

   //Function to sort by column
    $scope.sortData = function (column) {
        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ?
            !$scope.reverseSort : false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;
    }

    $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {

        if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
            return $scope.reverseSort
              ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'
              : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up';
        }

        return '';
    }
```

*note: sortData() and getSortClass() function does the sorting on each column when clicked.

The tables will look somewhat like this:

[click this to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmfp.png)

Comment: Yes,but i am struck for freezing header and column for the table which is render using angularjs,

Comment: <thead id="table-header">
            <tr  ng-repeat="taskHeader in TaskHeaderList">
                   <th>{{taskHeader}}</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>