# Evaluate $scope variable as value to a directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables, interpolation

I'm trying to hide a column by evaluating $scope.visibility value to a custom directive as attribute, but it's not working.

```
<td data-column-visible="visibility" data-table-property='id' data-table-property-type='button'>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="modal"
        ng-click="modify(user)">
        <i class="icon-pencil bigger-110"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
        ng-click="delete(user)">
        <i class="icon-trash bigger-110"></i>
    </button>                   
</td>
```

My directive :

```
'use strict';

define([ 'appModule' ], function(app) {
    // see example
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242455/using-jquery-datatable-with-angularjs
    app.directive('appDatatable', [ '$rootScope', '$compile', function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var _buildAoColumnDefs = function(scope, tableElement, tableData) {
                ....
                var defs = {
                    "mData": _tdElement.data("tableProperty"), "aTargets":[index], "bVisible": _tdElement.data("columnVisible")
                };
                ....
            return result;
        };
            return {
                scope : {
                    ...
                    columnVisible: "="
                },
                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

                    // Watch changing aaData.
                    var dataTable = null;
                    scope.$watch('aaData', function(value) {
                        ...
                        var aoColumnDefs = scope.aoColumnDefs || _buildAoColumnDefs(scope, element, value);
                        ... 
                    }, true);
                }
            };
        }]);
    });
```

It always evaluates to "visibility" instead of true/false.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-column-visible="visibility"` the visibility which you pass from your controller should be a primitive value... that's why its not changing as it create a new `scope`.

In your controller it should be `$scope.visibility` = true or false. Change that to an object.

```
$scope.someObject = {}
$scope.someObject.visibility = true or false
```

Its always advice to pass a `object`, not `primitives`.

Comment: I replaced `visibility`by `someObject.visibility` in my `$scope`, and i still do have the same problem. When i `console.log(_tdElement.data("columnVisible"))` i'm still getting `someObject.visibility`

Comment: inside your link function create scope.columnVisible = columnVisible and now pass that to your _tdElement.data

Comment: I get a `ReferenceError: columnVisible is not defined` and you want to me to pass `scope.columnVisible` like `_tdElement.data(scope.columnVisible)` ?

Comment: You need to pass the scope variable to                         var aoColumnDefs = scope.aoColumnDefs || _buildAoColumnDefs(scope, element, value); here...

Comment: since you are already passing the scope there... collect it like this.. _tdElement.data(scope.columnVisible)

Comment: `scope.columnVisible` is undefined, in both the`link` function and when used by `_tdElement.data(scope.columnVisible)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121537/discussion-between-redace-and-thalaivar).

Comment: Can you print out visibility in your view and check if value is passed.

Comment: can you do a scope.columnVisible = scope.columnVisible; and then check... or even remove this line in link if you have added and check